# Can't set primary colour of ElevatedButton in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an elevated button in Flutter, generally the button works fine.

However, the setting of the `primary: Colors.red` in this example does not work, the button is transparent for some reason... All the other params of the `ElevatedButton.styleFrom()` are working as expected.

Any assistance would be appreciated!

```
Widget _btnGood() {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: null,
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: Colors.purple,
          side: const BorderSide(width: 8.0, color: Colors.white),
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32)),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
        ),
        child: const Text(
          "Im Feeling Good",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 30,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[Example of Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycd6H.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change on pressed to-
`on_pressed: (){}` instead of null.

Comment: Legend, I feel like an idiot. I was just putting `null` to work around not having the onPressed target set yet. Working now!

Comment: Haha! It's a silly mistake! Just take note that on_pressed can't deliberately be assigned as null, though it can be empty. Good luck with your projects!